# JS async/await doesn't wait for my functions to resolve their promise

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise, aurelia

Can you help me understand why this doesn't work:

I'm working in Aurelia, and I try to validate some input data using the validation controller, which is documented here: https://aurelia.io/docs/plugins/validation#validation-controller

Now, I have a map of this data, where I need to evaluate each entry, and I want to create an array, where each item contains the validation result of each entry, and when everything is done, return the array.

So something like this (simplified):

```
function ValidateAll(InputDataMap){
  let validationResults = new Array();

  InputDataMap.forEach((item) => {
     validationResults.push(validateEntry(item));
  });

 return validationResults;
}

function validateEntry(item){

(aurelia's validation)controller.validate(item, "some value", "some rule")
      .then(result => {
        return result;
      });
}
```

Now, this will not work of course, because I need to wait for the validation controller to resolve it's promise before I can get any data back, and so far I've failed at that.

I read that if you use the async/await keyword it will pause a function until the promise has been resolved, so I made changes, something like this:

```
function ValidateAll(InputDataMap){
      let validationResults = new Array();

      InputDataMap.forEach(async(item) => {

         let result = await validateEntry(item);
         validationResults.push(result);
});
```

Now, this doesn't work either, and that's what I'm wondering about. I suppose that my "validateEntry" function is considered finished by the "await" once it's run, and doesn't wait for the "validate()" function's promise inside "validateEntry" to be resolved. Can I write it as simply as this with a few modifications and still get it to work?

Comment: You could try using `Promise.all` to get all the results.

Comment: Yes, I tried something like this, based on an example I saw:


let validate = InputDataArray.map((value) => {

        return validateEntry(value);

});
        
let validationResultObjects = Promise.all(validate);

validationResultObjects.then(()=> {

console.log="done";
});

But even after the Promise.all finished (running "then"), it had not resolved the promise within validateEntry. So I got no further,,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return a Promise from your `validateEntry`:

```
function validateEntry(item){
  return controller.validate(item, "some value", "some rule")
}
```

A `then` just returning its parameter is not required, and does nothing, so `.then(result => { return result; })` can be removed.

The `async` callback for the `forEach` would not make `ValidateAll` to wait for the validation. You have to wait for all Promises to be resolved, and return a Promise from `ValidateAll`, the `forEach` can be replaced by `map` so that you don't need to do the push manually:

```
let validationResults = new Array();

validationResults = InputDataMap.map(item => validateEntry(item));
```

You don't need `async` here because you do not need an `await` here. Now `validationResults` contains a list of Promises. You now need to use `Promise.all` to wait until those are resolved.

```
function ValidateAll(InputDataMap){
  let validationResults = InputDataMap.map(item => validateEntry(item));

  return Promise.all(validationResults);
}
```

Now `ValidateAll` will return a Promise that will resolve with an array containing the results of the validation.

You could shorten the code even more to:

```
function ValidateAll(InputDataMap){
  return Promise.all( InputDataMap.map(validateEntry) );
}
```

Comment: Ah, this made everything clearer, and helped me fix my code, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I read that if you use the async/await keyword it will pause a function until the promise has been resolved, so I made changes, something like this:

Indeed it does pause the function but `async(item) => {//Code}` is another function unaffected by the outer function

```
async function ValidateAll(InputDataMap){
      let validationResults = [];
      for (item of InputDataMap) {
          let result = await validateEntry(item);
          validationResults.push(result);
      }
      return validationResults;      
});
```

Also notice the `async` keyword in front of the function declaration, which mean you have to use it via `let results = await ValidateAll(inputData)` or like `ValidateAll(inputData).then(results => {//Code})`

```
function ValidateAll(InputDataMap){
      return Promise.all(InputDataMap.map(item => validateEntry(item)))
});
```

Comment: A `return await` does not make much sense, it will wait for the resolve of the Promise just to pass the result to a new Promise that is implicitly created by `async`, so you could omit the `await` there. And without a `await` the `async` is not required anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You have to return a Promise containing all the async operations, something like this:

```
function ValidateAll(InputDataMap) {
  return Promise.all(InputDataMap.map(item => validateEntry(item)));
}
```